# Execute less compiler anywhere on the computer

Tags: css, batch-file, cmd, less

Orginial source what I followed: http://blog.dotsmart.net/2010/11/26/running-the-less-js-command-line-compiler-on-windows/

I'm having a little problem with executing *.cmd files so I can execute them anywhere on the computer with cmd. 
What I exactly want is to execute the less.cmd file, which support optional arguments and uses lessc.wsf (Less.js compiler for Windows Script Host) for converting less css to pure css.

The lessc.cmd contains:

```
::For convenience
@cscript //nologo "%~dp0lessc.wsf" %*
```

The lessc.wsf contains this: http://pastebin.com/D4pUSGZ6

What I've done so far:

added absolute path to lessc.cmd to the PATH system variable and moved .cmd in the PATHTEXT system variable to the beginning.

Also did this:

```
From a command prompt; 
assoc .cmd
should return with 
..cmd=cmdfile
If not 
assoc .cmd=cmdfile 
to restore the default file type association. 

ftype cmdfile
should return with 
cmdfile="%1" %* 
If not 
ftype cmdfile="%1" %* 
to restore the default "Open" action for the file type.
```

This still doesn't work unless I approach the cmd file with a absolute path in cmd, if I enter lessc anywhere else then I get

```
C:\Intel Intel is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

, I've restarted my computer more than once to be sure changes will take effect.

I hope somebody has the answer.

Comment: Afaik, "PATHEXT" (not PATHTEXT) already contains .cmd by default. If your wrapper script is called "less.cmd", I don't think you will need to perform any ftype/assoc changes. Next, if you have added the absolute path of less.cmd to PATH, you should try to run "less" or "less.cmd" with arguments. In the last part of your question, you said you enter "lessc".

Comment: The association of the extension `.bat` has nothing to do with running a `.cmd` file. Where does the "C:\Intel" come from, i.e. how are you actually calling the batch file?

Comment: Oh oops, I made a typo with less.cmd and with the .bat assoc, its name is lessc.cmd and I've tried to run lessc.cmd more than once now. I also did where lessc.* and it found my lessc.cmd.

Comment: I don't really know what happens exactly, but when I write lessc anywhere else than the directory where lessc.cmd resides, a lot of lessc gets executed, as it is looping or something unless I do ctrl+c where I get prompted Y/N to terminate the batch command.

Comment: We don't really know what happens exactly, either, because we don't have a full log of the interaction.  Please show the exact commands you're running, the directories from which you're running them, and the exact output for those commands.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have another, runnable "less.*" file on your PATH that is shadowing your "less.cmd" file.  If you run

```
where less.*
```

from a directory other than the one containing less.cmd, does it list your file?

Also, try adding

```
echo Running less.cmd (as %0) with parameters %*
```

as the first line in your less.cmd file and then run your commands, again.  Do you always see the message, or only when running it by full path?  What is the full text of the commands you're running and this output?  What is your full path (i.e. the output from "set PATH")?

One more thing: check that your "lessc.wsf" file is actually located in the same folder as your "less.cmd" file.  I'm not sure how your script would ever run, if this were not the case, but it's still worth double-checking.

Comment: I executed the where less.* command and it showed the correct file. The lessc.wsf is located in the same directory, which is C:\lesscompiler. If you want to view the wsf file, I've put in pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/D4pUSGZ6 If it is helpfull here's the link to the orginial webpage where I got the files from: http://blog.dotsmart.net/2010/11/26/running-the-less-js-command-line-compiler-on-windows/

Comment: I also want to add that there're some test files for testing out the compiler and it works for me but not when using it anywhere else: This is what it does: `@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
set TEST_FILE="less-test-out.css"
call ..\lessc.cmd test.less > %TEST_FILE%
echo n | comp test-expected.css %TEST_FILE% /A 2> nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo === PASS ===
    del %TEST_FILE%
) else (
    echo === FAIL ===
)
popd`

Comment: Please put "echo Running lessc.cmd (as %0) with parameters %*" at the beginning of your batch file, run it for the failure case, and provide the whole log of the command prompt interaction (i.e. all of the command you're running, the prompt showing the current directory, and all the resulting output) in another pastebin.  (It would also be helpful for you to change that test file's "@echo off" into "echo on" and provide the log of that command prompt interaction, too.)  Thanks!

Comment: I did what you told me. This is the outcome for the lessc.cmd: http://pastebin.com/Km473Qgd and the other outcome for the lessc.cmd + comparison test: http://pastebin.com/i7sfh3g5 It works just fine when running it with absolute paths but I tried it again this time from a different directory. The lessc.cmd is still not recognized by cmd.

Comment: @Xenioz: Thanks!  Unfortunately, I can't find the "C:\Intel Intel is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error message in either of those.  Isn't that the error blocking the scenario you're trying to fix?  Can you please run the commands that result in errors and provide the logs of those attempts?

Comment: I'm not getting that intel error anymore, just that lessc.cmd not recognized etc..

Comment: OK; that is helpful.  Run "set PATH & where lessc.*" from C:\ .  After that, run "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\lesscompiler" and then rerun your "lessc test/test.less workingoutput.css -compress" command--all from the *same* command prompt and without changing the directory away from C:\ .

Comment: Okay, thanks @Mattias Andersson ! this is much better however im getting a Microsoft JScript runtime error: http://pastebin.com/que4Xj3c which is very strange because when being in the same directory as the lessc.cmd, it just works. The file for javascript is this: http://pastebin.com/cmTD77M6

Comment: I wanted to add to my last comment that the javascript (http://pastebin.com/cmTD77M6) is called by the lessc.wsf on line 84 `<script language="jscript" src="less-1.3.0.js" />`, the .wsf file: http://pastebin.com/D4pUSGZ6

Comment: I've changed inside the wsf file the path of the js script to `<script language="jscript" src="c:\lesscompiler\less-1.3.0.js" />` but didn't work. When I use the absolute path to the input less file it works. But I don't get why it won't work with test/test.less for example: `c:\>lessc test/test.less workingoutput.css -compress`

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  To set the path permanently, on your machine, refer to http://superuser.com/questions/317631/setting-path-in-windows-7-command-prompt and http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them .  This question about the path should probably be migrated to SuperUser and duped to those.  Please start a new StackOverflow question for your JavaScript error and include the link to the blog post and these latest comments (including both working and failing command lines and outputs! :-) ).  Thanks!